# Dynamically setting polymer custom element event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer, custom-element

I have created a custom element (admin-button.html) which contains the following code:

```
<polymer-element name="admin-button">
  <template>
    <paper-item class="chip-container" hero-p>
      <div class="chip" hero-id="addPres" hero>
        <div class="chip-top" hero-id="addPres-art" hero></div>
        <div class="chip-bottom" cross-fade>
          <div class="chip-title-overlay" title="Create presentation"></div>
          <div class="chip-title">Create presentation</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </paper-item>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

In another file (table-body.html), which is itself a custom element, I am dynamically importing this file, creating an instance of the element and appending it to a menu-list (#chip-menu), like so:

```
<script>
  var poly = this;

  Polymer.import(["elements/admin-button.html"], function() {
    var button = document.createElement("admin-button");
    poly.$.chipMenu.appendChild(button);
  });
</script>
```

No problems up to here. But now I want to give this newly created button an "on-tap" event handler. I tried to simply set the attribute with

```
button.setAttribute("on-tap", "{{ eventHandler }}");
```

but this did not work - I suspect it has something to do with registring the element properly, but I cannot seem to find any hint on how to dynamically set event handlers on custom elements in the polymer docs.

If I hard-code the element into the HTML like this

```
<admin-button on-tap="{{ eventHandler}}"></admin>
```

and instantiate the element with

```
Polymer.import(["elements/admin-button.html"]);
```

it works. But I do not want to have the custom element in the HTML code on page load.

Can this be done?

Comment: What version of Polymer are you using?  I have never come across Polymer.import before, and others may wonder about this too.  You might also want to look at addEventListener(...) rather than setAttribute(...)

Comment: I am running version 0.5.5 and I picked up the hint about Polymer.import here: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/helpers.html ...addEventListener is working apparently, I just cannot use pre-defined functions inside the parent-element it seems, but instead have to write an anonymous handler function.

Comment: Ah, then I do work in the Polymer Dart world, mostly.  Thanks for the link, and I'm glad things are working for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `button.addEventListener('tap',eventHandler);`.

Answer (score 0):

not very clear, but try this:

```html
<polymer-element name="admin-button" attributes="eventHandler">
...
<paper-item class="chip-container" hero-p on-tap="{{ eventHandler}}">
...
```